# Query taking to long tuning advice please

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, query-performance

I have a collection of `SQL Server` tables containing survey information and I would like to run a query which has one row for each survey and one column for each answer.

The structure is setup like so:

```
ResponseHeader:
 ID (record for each survey)

Responses:
 ID 
 responseHeaderID
 questionID
 answerItemsID

AnswerItems:
 ID   (This is the value needed in each answer column)
 answerText
```

The following is the query which I have come up with:

```
SELECT  ResponseHeader.id
    ,   ResponseHeader.YOS
    ,   ResponseHeader.rankID
    ,   ResponseHeaderunitID
    ,   ResponseHeader.age
    ,   ResponseHeader.gender
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN Responses.questionID = 42 THEN AnswerItems.id END)
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN Responses.questionID = 43 THEN AnswerItems.id END)
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN Responses.questionID = 44 THEN AnswerItems.id END)
    , --.....there are 79 of these lines in the query, one for each question (Responses.questionID)
        MAX(CASE WHEN Responses.questionID = 48 THEN AnswerItems.id END)
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN Responses.questionID = 48 THEN AnswerItems.id END)
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN Responses.questionID = 50 THEN AnswerItems.id END)
    ,   MAX(CASE WHEN Responses.questionID = 49 THEN AnswerItems.id END)
FROM ResponseHeader
LEFT OUTER JOIN Responses ON ResponseHeader.id = Responses.responseHeaderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AnswerItems ON Responses.answerItemsID = AnswerItems.id
WHERE completed = 1
GROUP BY
        ResponseHeader.id
    ,   YOS
    ,   rankID
    ,   unitID
    ,   age
    ,   gender
ORDER BY ResponseHeader.id;
```

It does return the correct result set but it takes 18 seconds to execute in Query Analyzer. It returns 4592 rows and it has 85 columns. Unfortunately it reaches the `IIS` buffer limit therefore is considered to time consuming to use in a classic ASP page.  Increasing the buffer limit is not an option for the job. I am unsure how to get this information any other way.

I was reading about pivot queries but did not understand them. Is there a way to get my results using this or any other method quicker?

Comment: @Mat41 . . . I would rewrite this as a `pivot` query to see if that improves the performance.

Comment: The lines you talk about are giving me a column for each answer.  I wrote this query so there was a row for each answer which gave me 320000 rows.  This was the only way I could figure out how to achieve a row for each survey (ResponseHeader.id) and a column for each answer. @Gordon I have been reading about these pivot queries but are having trouble understanding them, could you offer me some help by any chance?

Comment: @Mat41 . . . You should edit the query to include table aliases, so someone reading the question has some idea of where the columns are coming from.

Comment: Not including the schemas and not using qualified column names makes it rather more difficult for those of us out here to help you.  Perhaps you could edit your question (and query) to provide a some additional context.

Comment: @Mat41 have you tried query given by devart ??

Comment: @Dhaval just starting for the day and are looking at it now.  I have commented below the issues Query Analyser talks about.  To be honest I dont fully understand the query so I am going through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
DECLARE @Responses TABLE (responseHeaderID INT, questionID INT, answerItemsID INT)
DECLARE @ResponseHeader TABLE (id INT, YOS INT, rankID INT, unitID INT, age INT, gender CHAR(1), completed BIT)

SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
          rh.id
        , rh.YOS
        , rh.rankID
        , rh.unitID
        , rh.age
        , rh.gender
    FROM @ResponseHeader rh
    WHERE completed = 1
) rh
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              r.responseHeaderID
            , r.questionID 
            , r.answerItemsID
        FROM @Responses r
    ) t
    PIVOT 
    (
        MAX(answerItemsID) FOR questionID IN ([42], [43], [44], [48], [50], [49])
    ) p
) t2 ON rh.id = t2.responseHeaderID
ORDER BY rh.id
```

Output -

[image]

Comment: I need to learn about these, looks complicated...  QA tells me there are four issues.  The first two refer to 'a.' and 'r.' in this line'MAX(a.id) FOR r.questionID IN' it says 'does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query'. The it saying 't.responseHeaderID' can not be bound and 'responseHeaderID' was specified multiple times for 'cte'

Comment: Yes that works extremely well thank you!  Wow my original query took 18 seconds.  When I place all 85 elements in the '[42], [43], [44], [48], [50], [49]' section, using your pivot query it takes less than 1 second.  I am amazed.  One question, why does the questionID values have to be surrounded by []? Usually when ever I say WHERE IN, a comer delimited string is allowed.  How come this can not be used in this situation, because of the 'FOR' I assume?

Comment: Numeric values which are contained in `IN` construction is column names after pivoting. So you can't specify a column name by the number without using brackets. Additional information you read here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/08/28/sql-server-tips-for-sql-query-optimization-by-analyzing-query-plan/